# Index of line textfile using StreamReader vb.net

Tags: vb.net

How can I use this code?

```
TextBox1.Text = Array.FindIndex(linestring, Function(s) s.Contains(something))
```

but to use the code, without a word, and to display my array index following the code below:

```
Dim lines As New List(Of String)
    
Using reader As New StreamReader(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath + ("\Data.txt"))
    
    Dim line As String
    
    Do Until line.StartsWith(endPrefix)

        lines.Add(line)
        line = reader.ReadLine()

        'maybe here index of array 

    Loop
```

so how do I use this to get the line index from my text files?

Comment: Doing `lines.Add(line)` then `line = reader.ReadLine()` does not get the new line into lines until the next iteration, so the first one is empty, and the last one is actually the second to last line (you never add the last line), because string is immutable and both a reference and value type, but in the case above you must treat it as a value type. Switch the order of those instructions to get the latest line. However I don't understand your question and I'm not sure if this addresses your actual issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example which uses the [File.ReadLines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readlines) method (which enumerates the lines of a file) where you can pass the predicate for the comparison to get the line number (starting at 1) of the first match:

```
Imports System.IO

Module Module1

    Function FindLineNumber(sourceFile As String, textToFind As String, predicate As Func(Of String, String, Boolean)) As Integer
        Dim lineNo = 1

        For Each l In File.ReadLines(sourceFile)
            If predicate(l, textToFind) Then
                Return lineNo
            End If
            lineNo += 1
        Next

        Return -1

    End Function

    Sub Main()
        ' File to look in:
        Dim src = "C:\temp\population.csv"
        ' Text to find:
        Dim find = "133"

        Dim lineNum = FindLineNumber(src, find, Function(a, b) a.Contains(b))

        If lineNum > 0 Then
            Console.WriteLine($"""{find}"" found at line {lineNum}.")
        Else
            Console.WriteLine($"""{find}"" not found.")
        End If

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```